# how do I reproduce the native crash for Android？

Tags: android, native

For example, I have a native crash for android project,  it comes from issue of  Fluter project https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112923.

Now, I can reproduce the issue by the discribable step of the issue. As we konw, native crash is caught linux OS kernel, linux OS kernel sent exceptional signals. Thus, can I reproduce is by simulating exception signals from the linux kernel? Please, how do I do it？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to reproduce the native crash by simulating handle signal form linux. I want to know which tools can simulting signal from linux. Thank you for comment.

Comment: Sounds to me like what you're trying to do would only reproduce a symptom of the bug, instead of the bug itself. I'm not sure sure how that would help you fix the bug(?).

Comment: I'm not thinking about whether the bug can be fixed. I think symptom of bug is crash reports, and bug itself is the erroring line in corresponding source code. If my understanding is correct, I reproduce the symptom of bug.  I just reproduce the symptom of bug by simulting signal from linux. What tools are likely to be used？ And do you have some better advice?

Answer (score 0):

I quickly skimmed the bug report. The SIGABRT raised is a direct result of an `abort()` system call:

```
backtrace:
     #00 pc 00000000000830f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160) (BuildId: cf739dbc84bcc78f7a1500721bfb3758)
```

It is clear that this abort is called because there is a pending Java exception in a bit of JNI code:

```
F/flutter (10735): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1319)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).
```

and the cause is right above in the logs:

```
E/OpenGLRenderer(10735): [SurfaceTexture-0-10735-1] bindTextureImage: error binding external image: 0x502  
E/flutter (10735): [ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(204)] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error during updateTexImage (see logcat for details)  
E/flutter (10735):  at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeUpdateTexImage(Native Method)  
E/flutter (10735):  at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage(SurfaceTexture.java:248)  
E/flutter (10735):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.renderer.SurfaceTextureWrapper.updateTexImage(SurfaceTextureWrapper.java:55)  
E/flutter (10735):
```

Instead of hunting the symptoms, you should investigate why this `bindTextureImage` call failed, which will require finding out where it was created and/or updated first.

Comment: I see about you comment. But, I want to reproduce the crash by two way. One is the crash is reproduced manually by the step in crash report. Other is the crash is reproduced by simulting signal from linux. I just want to reproduce the crash by simulting signal from linux, and don't considering repairing the bug.

Comment: I guess just use `kill` to send a SIGSEGV, I guess. No idea what you hope to accomplish with that though.

Comment: How do I  do it?  Can you tell me the command?

Comment: It should be as simple as `kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV)` if you are inside the process, or `kill -SIGSEGV $PID` from the commandline.

Comment: I killed the process that is a SIGSEGV. It appears to be a crash report, but my report's erroring line isn't the original one. What should I do to reproduce the original report for an exception type, erroring function, and erroring lines？

Comment: By redoing the steps in the issue with the same hardware and software and probably other circumstances. I already told you that the signal is a symptom, not the cause.

Comment: `Tombstone files --> .so file --> c source code (native crash source code) --> test generation tool --> test cases --> run test cases --> crash reproduction` I want to reproduce the native crash as the wrokflow, is it possible?

Comment: For the third time now,  the error is dependent on the phone it is running on and some unknown parts of its configuration. If you cannot reproduce the crash as-is there is no point in what you are doing.

Comment: thank you for your comments. However, Java crashes can be reproduced by running test cases.

Comment: Not this one. But I will refrain from explaining for a fourth time.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I will reproduce it by other way.

Comment: If the signal is `SIGSEGV`, can it be reproduced?